# React & AngularJS SPA in parallel for migration

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, migration

Hello dear SO community,

I'm preparing a project that has the requirement of migrating an AngularJS application to a new React application. The AngularJS application is actually two separate AngularJS applications (*componentA*, *componentB*). They are getting served statically via CloudFront.

The task is about the migration from the two AngularJS applications *componentA* and *componentB* to **one** React application. But of course, since it's a productive project, I cannot go with a big bang solution here and replace everything after half a year of migrating to React.

**My question**: with the given infos above, is it possible to have two AngularJS applications running and the React application at the same time on the same domain www.example.com? The idea is then to migrate site by site until all sites are fully migrated.

I know about stuff like react2angular, but it's requested explicitly to create a React app from scratch for the migration. Any tipp is welcome :)

Comment: It's impossible to suggest anything without knowing what are these apps and how they work.

Comment: *I know about stuff like react2angular, but it's requested explicitly to create a React app from scratch for the migration* - what's the problem with creating it from scratch? Isn't it what you want? Any way, it's just tiny helper library. You can use it in any way you like. You can check how it works if you need some custom solution for some reason.

Comment: @estus The apps are completely isolated. One is like a public app with information, the other one secured with a login. I will happily give more information, but maybe you have more specific questions? :)

It is totally fine to build the app(s) from scratch. But when using react2angular for example, the migration is a little easier, because you do not have two complete separate projects, but one.

Comment: So apps don't coexist on single page. I don't see reasons why you need to make them a single app if they are different apps in fact. You just need to rebuild AngularJS components to React components one by one or several at ones. The feasibility of this totally depends on how AngularJS app was written. If it was properly componentized there will be much less problems. It's generally easier to host React components in Angular wrapper rather than the opposite, due to differences between their lifecycles.

Comment: As I said, https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular/blob/master/index.tsx is just tiny helper. You could write it from scratch for any component depending on your needs for this component. You pass directive attributes as props, `render` React component on directive init and unmount it on directive destroy. Simple as that. All possible obstacles totally depend on your particular app.

Comment: @estus thank you very much for your input. I will rethink here and probably change to the way of rebuilding the applications then... :)